# Is there a way to backup/restore/upgrade the stateless part of a Minikube cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-registry

I want to take a snapshot of all stateless components inside a Minikube cluster without the persistent data and then restore it in another Minikube cluster.

Is there a way to dump all kube spec + docker images and then restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no really specific tool only for `minikube` cluster. Even on their Github page you can find [information](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9991#issuecomment-897188649) from August 11 2021 that they are not ready with it yet.

However, there are few solutions to backup the Kubernetes cluster in general. Maybe you will find it useful.

The first one is a tool called `velero`. It has pretty good and solid [documentation](https://velero.io/docs/v1.6/index.html). [Here](https://zufardhiyaulhaq.com/backup-kubernetes-cluster-using-velero/) you can find a brief tutorial how to setup and run it on the Kubernetes cluster setup on `minikube`.

To not backup specific resources you can use [resource-filtering](https://velero.io/docs/v1.6/resource-filtering/). For example, you can setup `velero` not to backup persistent volumes and persistent volumes claims.

```
velero backup create <backup-name> --exclude-resources persistentvolumes,persistentvolumeclaims
```

You can also use a tool called `k8up`. To get started with it you can follow [tutorial](https://k8up.io/k8up/1.2.0/tutorials/tutorial.html) from their website. The tutorial explains how to backup Kubernetes cluster setup on `minkube`.

To not to backup specific resources you can use `k8up.syn.tools/backup` [annotation](https://k8up.io/k8up/1.2.0/references/annotations.html). This [tutorial](https://github.com/vshn/k8up-tutorial) has an example with usage of this annotation (3.3.1 paragraph).

For docker images, I would recommend just setting up and using registry in the cloud, for example [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or some cloud provider solution, like [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry) or [Amazon Elastic Container Registry](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/). You can setup them as private so your images will be safe.